# Tooltip issue using Dataset

Tags: dataset, tooltip

When I try to create a tooltip for a Dataset item, I get `...` instead of the item value. See the toy code example below:

```
tooltipValue =  Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}];

Dataset[{
    <|"colA" -> 1, "colB" -> Tooltip[1, tooltipValue]|>
  , <|"colA" -> 2, "colB" -> Tooltip[2, tooltipValue]|>
  }]
```

[image: Dataset]

How can I force the value in column B to be `1` and `2` instead of `...` ?

Comment: Use option ``ItemDisplayFunction -> (# &)`` in ``Dataset``.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the version 12.1 on, you can use option `ItemDisplayOption -> (# &)`. By default, it is set to `Automatic`, which does some preprocessing and converts large items to ellipsis.

```
tooltipValue = Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}];

Dataset[{<|"colA" -> 1, "colB" -> Tooltip[1, tooltipValue]|>, <|
   "colA" -> 2, "colB" -> Tooltip[2, tooltipValue]|>}, 
 ItemDisplayFunction -> (# &)]
```

[image: Dataset]

Comment: Also see [`Identity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Identity.html) for the `ItemDisplayFunction`.

Comment: @Edmund, I did try that but ``ItemDisplayFunction -> Identity`` did not work.

Comment: `ItemDisplayFunction -> (Identity[#] &)` works but this is less elegant than your solution.

Comment: Read `ItemDisplayFunction`'s documentation. The function takes 3 parameters. `({i, p, d} |-> i)` for example.

Comment: @Edmund, yes, I know. But I don't see any advantage (or difference) in using ``Identity`` instead of a shorthand pure function.